# ViewPager Lagging Issues in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am having problem in ViewPager Smoothly Swiping. My goal is to download the images  from URL using Volley Library and must shown downloaded images in ViewPager without any lagging issue during swiping left to right or right to left. I have attached the code which is lag during swiping the images.

This is my Activity class which contains view pager:

ViewPagerActivity.java

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends Activity {
ViewPager pager;
String[] URL;
PagerAdapter objPagerAdapter;
ArrayList<String> _arrayImagePath=new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);
    pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pagerView);

    // Setting the 70 images URL 
    URL= new String[] { "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg",
            "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg",
            "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg",
            "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg",
            "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg",
            "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg",
            "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg",
            "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg",
            "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg",
            "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/7/71/PollutionAura2.png/revision/latest?cb=20101211235024",
            "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/aread/images/6/6f/V02_Back.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140501154842", 
            "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tmnt/images/d/d5/Tnmt-disneyscreencaps_com-5817.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130428155629",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Sunset_at_Selsey_beach_4.jpg",
            "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140806200752/disney/images/d/d8/Little-mermaid-1080p-disneyscreencaps.com-782.jpg",
            "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141022183927/howtotrainyourdragon/images/c/c5/When_gothi_drops_that_flag_we_race.jpg",
            "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17jy4w1lonvyijpg/original.jpg"
             };

    objPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(ViewPagerActivity.this, _arrayImagePath);
    pager.setAdapter(objPagerAdapter);

    // Calling Volley Library to Download the Image for each URLi

    for(int i=0;i<URL.length;i++)
    {
        DownloadImages(URL[i], i);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_pager, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
void DownloadImages(String imageURL_in,final int counter_in)
{
    final String counter=String.valueOf(counter_in);
    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(imageURL_in,
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(final Bitmap response) {
            try{
                Log.v("Response Received =",""+counter_in);
                // Saved in SD Card and getting the Path
                String imagePath = SavedInSDCard(response, counter + "_hires"); 
                //Added ImagePath 
                _arrayImagePath.add(imagePath);
                // Notifying the Adapter
                objPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }, 0, 0, null, null);
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(imageRequest);



}
public String SavedInSDCard(Bitmap bitmap2, String dishId) {

    File dir = new File(ApplicationController.getAppContext()
            .getExternalFilesDir("ViewPager_POC") + "/Cache");
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    String stDishID = dishId;
    String formatedDsihID = stDishID.replace(":", "R");
    File file = new File(dir, formatedDsihID);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String imgPath = dir + "/" + formatedDsihID;
    return imgPath;
}
```

This is my xml file:

activity_view_pager.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.poc_viewpager.ViewPagerActivity" >

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pagerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /></RelativeLayout>
```

This is my ViewPager item xml file:

view_pager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is adapter class of the View Pager:

ViewPagerAdapter.class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
Context _context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

ArrayList<String> _arrayImagePath;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context_in, ArrayList<String> imagePath_in) {
    _arrayImagePath=imagePath_in;
    _context = context_in;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _arrayImagePath.size();
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtCounter;
    ImageView imgView;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, container,
            false);

    txtCounter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
    imgView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.images);

    //Setting the values for Image and textview
    txtCounter.setText(""+(position+1));        
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_arrayImagePath.get(position));
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

}
```

Suggest any idea to resolve this lag?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a good idea to use `decodeFile` on the UI Thread cause it might take a while. You could an AsyncTask for example.

Take a look at the android developer side, there is a pretty good guide:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

And change add something like this to your code:

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String path = params[0];
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And in your `instantiateItem` you can use:

```
BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imgView);
task.execute(_arrayImagePath.get(position));
```

Haven't tested it, but it should help to understand the problem.
Please edit the code if you find and error.